# Distributed build system for Rust

Tags: open-source, software-development, distributed, rust

I'm looking for a distributed build system for [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/) that:

- Is free, gratis and opensource
- Is cross-platform and cross-compiles (from ARMv6, ARMv7, i386 and amd64 Linux and amd64 Windows for amd64 Linux and preferably also ARMv8 Android)
- Has low impact on my network
- Does what `cargo build` does but in distributed form
- Caches compiler output
- Utilizes all threads unless the thread is busy with something else (over 60% usage)